# Loop a sequence in R (standardize and winsorize dataframe)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, standardized

I'm trying to loop this sequence of steps in r for a data frame.
Here is my data:

```
ID  Height  Weight    
a   100  80    
b  80  90    
c  na  70    
d  120  na    
....
```

Here is my code so far

```
winsorize2 <- function(x) {        
Min <- which(x == min(x))
Max <- which(x == max(x))
ord <- order(x)
x[Min] <- x[ord][length(Min)+1]
x[Max] <- x[ord][length(x)-length(Max)]
x}

df<-read.csv("data.csv")
df2 <- scale(df[,-1], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
id<-df$Type
full<-data.frame(id,df2) 
full[is.na(full)] <- 0
full[, -1] <- sapply(full[,-1], winsorize2)
```

what i'm trying to do is this:-> Standardize a dataframe, then winsorize the standardized dataframe using the function winsorize2, ie replace the most extreme values with the second least extreme value. This is then repeated 10 times. How do i do a loop for this? Im confused as in the sequence ive already replaced the nas with 0s and so i should remove this step from the loop too?

edit:After discussion with @ekstroem, we decided to change to code to introduce the boundaries

```
df<-read.csv("data.csv")  
id<-df$Type  
df2<- scale(df[,-1], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)  
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2[df2<=-3] = -3
df2[df2>=3] = 3

df3<-df2  #trying to loop again
df3<- scale(df3, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)  
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0  
df3[df3<=-3] = -3  
df3[df3>=3] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some boundary issues that are not fully specified in your code, but maybe the following can be used (using base R and not super efficient)

```
wins2 <- function(x, n=1) { 
    xx <- sort(unique(x)) 
    x[x<=xx[n]] <- xx[n+1]
    x[x>=xx[length(xx)-n]] <- xx[length(xx)-n]
    x 
}
```

This yields:

```
x <- 1:11
wins(x,1)
[1]  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10
wins(x,3)
[1] 4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: Sorry but i meant how do i loop the standardizing and winsorizing? ie Standardize, then winsorize. Then standardize the winsorized scores and which are then winsorized again. And you're absolutely right! I do need a boundary. How do i replace those with more than +/- 3 sd from mean with 3? p.s should i edit my question? Sorry quite new at this. Thanks

Comment: With your code there's really no point in standardizing as the smallest value in the original data will still be the smallest after standardizing. You are essentially working on ranks and maybe you just want to standardize after the last run? Maybe try to rephrase the question so that is also shows what the output should be?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Im trying to assign a score to these values from a range of 0 to 100 which 50 being the mean. Also I'm trying to force the values into a normal distribution if that makes any sense? As for the output, i did it manually in excel and the edited code which i added to my original question did seem to give similar results. So i'm just looking to replicate the "standardizing the winsorized scores" and "winsorizing" sequence for 10 times. Thanks.